# rxjs emit constant value if no value was emitted in given timeframe

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have an observable that emits a values (it is emitting arrays) periodically.

How can I make it so that if there was no value for 2 seconds, a constant value (for example an empty array) should be emitted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) to create an observable that emits 2 items:

1. the original value
2. the empty array, after a delay of 2000 ms.

If `switchMap` receives another emission from the source, it will create a new inner observable without ever emitting the empty array.

```
const obs$ = source$.pipe(
    switchMap(source => 
      concat(
        of(source), 
        of([]).pipe(delay(2000))
      )
    )
);
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66532478?file=index.ts) sample.

---

You could even pull this logic out into its own custom operator:

```js
const obs$ = source$.pipe(
  onDormant(2000, [])
);
```

```js
/*
 | Emits the provided value when no emissions
 | occur after the specified time duration.
*/
function onDormant<T, V extends T>(delayMs: number, value: V) {
  return switchMap((source: T) => concat(
    of(source),
    timer(delayMs).pipe(mapTo(value as T))
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on how you are getting these arrays. But you can always update your observable to emit every 2 seconds since last emission using `setInterval`. This would ensure a *maximum* window of 2 seconds per message (but it can be much less)

For example:

```js
const observable = new Observable(function subscribe(subscriber) {
  var interval;  
  function resetInterval() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(() => subscriber.next([]), 2_000);
  }

  resetInterval();

  const subject = webSocket("ws://localhost:8081");

  subject.subscribe(
    msg => { subscriber.next(msg); resetInterval(); }
    err => subscriber.error
    () => console.log('complete') // Called when connection is closed (for whatever reason).
  );
});
```